# How do I get a Coupon for the Lumiose City Boutique?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

It seems that I've finally been able to get into the shop, but the prices are incredibly expensive.

There was a woman who mentioned being able to get a discount card, but no mention of how to get one.

How do I get a discount card for the shop?

Comment: The coupon is a lie! So far anyway... hopefully it gets figured out soon.

Comment: I have heard you can buy one from the Poke Miles store in Lumoise city (according to the official guide!) but neither I nor anyone I know has ever seen the coupon there. Unsure if there is a particular unlock condition or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Discount Coupon was available via Global Link until March 3, 2014 (thanks to @Jerry for finding that one out). If you got it until then, it will remain on your game until you use it or delete the save file.

*For reference, here is a description of how it was done, which might apply to similar future events:*
To get it, you simply need to create an account on 3ds.pokemon-gl.com, log in, register your game (use the in-game Game Sync feature to create a Game Sync ID) and click the right picture in the PokeMileage Club. The next time you use Game Sync, you will receive a Discount Coupon from the red Lady right of the PC in any Pokemon Center. You also get a confirmation on the PGL site once you've unlocked it.

Comment: The coupon is available until the 3rd of March :)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't heard of the time limit to get it. Guess its good I didn't want one.

Comment: March 3 is in the future. You can still get it ;)

Answer (score 3):

After searching the seribii itemdex and browsing Google search, I have found that this item does not exist. It may be released in a patch, though this is doubtful.

Sources: http://serebii.net/itemdex/

Update:

<strike>It seems this item does now exist, obtained through a game on the Global Link site and transferable to your game, it is good for one transaction of various items at any boutique.</strike>
While the item does exist, the game was a limited time deal and has since expired. It is possible it will be given out in other Global Link games later, however.

Answer (score 0):

i have heard that the poke'miles guy does sell it, however it depends on what medals you have earned (perhaps a medal related to style is needed before it unlocks).